# How to display Data of foreign key in Django html page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to display a Company header and the products below its related company. I am new to django i do not understand this fully.

My models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)


class Products(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="display")
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    cyl = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    bore = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.engine) + "  (ref:" + str(self.ref) + ")"
```

My views.py:

```
def Companies(request):
context = {
    'categories': Company.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'product_list.html', context)
```

My html:

```
                {% for category in categories %}
            <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
            {% for item in category.item_set.all %}
                {{ item_engine }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: in your html change to:  `category.display.all`. your related name is `display` not `item_set`

Comment: you've got a related_name='display' so I think you want `{% for item in display.all %}` and then `{{ item.engine }}` in your for loop. The `item` can be anything llike `{% for product in display.all %}` then reference in loop as `{{product.engine}}`

Comment: alternatively, remove the related_name attribute, then you can use `{% for product in products_set.all %}`

Comment: one further note, you probably want to name your `Products` class in the singular form `Product`. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only make changes to your HTML file as below and make sure the class name is Product if you are using product_set.all:

```
{% for category in categories %}
            <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
            {% for item in category.product_set.all %}
                {{ item.engine }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

If still not working then try to remove : ***+ "  (ref:" + str(self.ref) + ")"***
and also, I think by mistake you have displayed your models.py wrongly. The **str** functions should be inside the classes like below:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="display")
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    cyl = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    bore = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.engine)
```

Comment: This adds a new header to every product added..  suppose a company name FORD .. and product as (1) and (2) .. when i add (2) i want it under a single header below (1). but this makes (2) with a new ford header.

Comment: Ok, I got it then you have to make only change in your html as: {% for item in category.product_set.all %} {{item.engine}}, it must work, just make sure your product class name is Product, and if you are using Products as class name then, products_set.all